# Text when rotated are not at correct (aligned) positions in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, text

I wanted to rotate a text in my plot. A sample code would be like this:

```
plt.text(0.5, 0.0, 'ABC', fontsize=40, rotation=90)
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'DFG', fontsize=40, rotation=90)
```

But the said texts are not aligned properly. I have attached a figure to illustrate this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in matplotlib https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14239

Here the bbox is at the correct place but the text is not rendered in the correct position relative to the bbox